# Quicktime: Grey background upon resume in fullscreen mode

Tags: macos, quicktime, bug

A clip that was played in fullscreen mode will not appear in fullscreen mode.

Instead, it's slightly shifted, resized and has a grey background.

I've removed the Quicktime plug-in [Perian](http://perian.org/), but this behavior is persistent.

- What's causing this? How can I fix this?

[image: ----------]

Comment: I have the same problem, with no plugins or anything. I think it's a QuickTime bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an annoying bug in QuickTime Player. There isn't much you can do about it, I'm afraid.

Closing and then reopening the file usually fixes it, but if it doesn't you can try logging out and then back in.

If QuickTime gets so 'confused' that it can't open properly, quit using <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>opt</kbd>-<kbd>q</kbd> to prevent it from saving what's open. That should allow you to open it up and try again.

As always, file a bug report on the [Apple website](http://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html).

Comment: So, it's actually best then to simply disable resume for Quicktime, right?

Comment: @gentmatt Not a bad idea at all. I recommend [RestoreMeNot](http://restoremenot.info/).